# Using select to match a class and an element beautifulSoup error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image: What i want to take]

So i am using 'beautifulsoup at python to try to take some html info from a page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.meteo.gr/cf.cfm?city_id=14') #sending the request to take the html file.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') #creating beautifulSoup object of the html code.

four_days = soup.find("div", {"class": "content"})#PINPOINTING to the section that i want to focus (the outer).

#Selecting specific elements , having as my base the seven_day.
periods_times = [p.get_text(strip=True) for p in four_days.select(".perhour .fulltime")]
anemos = [sd.get_text("|", strip=True) for sd in four_days.select(".anemosfull")]
temps = [t.get_text("|", strip=True) for t in four_days.select(".temperature .tempcolorcell") ]
prognosi_ouranou =[pk.get_text("|", strip=True) for pk in four_days.select(".phenomenafull .phenomeno-name") ]


     drastiriotita_kounoupion =[po.get_text("|", strip=True) for po in four_days.select(".someclass .tr > title") ]

    #creating a Data Frame via pandas to print it TABLE-like.
        import pandas as pd
        weather = pd.DataFrame({
        "drastiriotita_kounoupion": drastiriotita_kounoupion})

        print weather
```

I get an error when i try something like this. I know how to use 2 classes in a selector but the info i want to take from the site is inside one class and this class contains the info in a  element.

Any suggestion. 
Thanks

i tried to find simmilar examples in the documentation but none of them really covers my question. 
[simmilar example]

```
css_soup.select("p.strikeout.body")
```